# How to construct a matrix of all possible differences of a vector in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, array-difference

I have a one dimensional array, lets say:

```py
import numpy as np
inp_vec = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

Now, I would like to construct a matrix of the form

```py
[[1 - 1, 1 - 2, 1 - 3],
 [2 - 1, 2 - 2, 2 - 3],
 [3 - 1, 3 - 2, 3 - 3]])
```

Of course it can be done with for loops but is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
In [1]: %paste
import numpy as np
inp_vec = np.array([1, 2, 3])

## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: inp_vec.reshape(-1, 1) - inp_vec
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0, -1, -2],
       [ 1,  0, -1],
       [ 2,  1,  0]])
```

Explanation:

You first reshape the array to `nx1`. When you subtract a 1D array, they are both broadcast to `nxn`:

```
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3]])
```

and

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  2,  3]])
```

Then the subtraction is done element-wise, which yields the desired result.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and the explanation, however can you point me to some reference explaining the expansion from nx1 to nxn. It's a bit mysterious. Also how do I know that the subtraction is made columnwise. Thanks

Comment: @user3176500 I guess it's not really correct to say that the subtraction is made column-wise or row-wise, see the edit. For a short explanation of the rules, check [this tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-c533fb9a3f1aa90d96e4d8329c1c2f975474c8bf).

Comment: sorry, missed the "they are both broadcast to nxn". Of course the subtraction is made element-wise. Thanks again

Comment: @user3176500 You didn't miss it, I edited the answer in response tou your comment :) Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 6):

This I find a nice way as well:

```
np.subtract.outer([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
inp_vec = np.array([1, 2, 3])

a, b = np.meshgrid(inp_vec, inp_vec)
print(b - a)
```

Output:

```
Array([[ 0 -1 -2],
       [ 1  0 -1],
       [ 2  1  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using  np.nexaxis

```
import numpy as np
inp_vec = np.array([1, 2, 3])

output = inp_vec[:, np.newaxis] - inp_vec
```

Output

```
array([[ 0, -1, -2],
       [ 1,  0, -1],
       [ 2,  1,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick and simple alternative.

```
import numpy as np
inp_vec = np.array([1, 2, 3])

N = len(inp_vec)
np.reshape(inp_vec,(N,1)) - np.reshape(inp_vec,(1,N))
```