# Calculating distance between each element of an array

Tags: numpy, permutation

I have an array,

```py
a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 10])
```

I would like to create a function that calculates the distance between each of its elements from every other element. There should be no for loop as speed is critical.

The expected result of the above would be:

```
array([[0, 2, 4, 9],
       [2, 0, 2, 7],
       [4, 2, 0, 5],
       [9, 7, 5, 0]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to construct a matrix of all possible differences of a vector in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053914/how-to-construct-a-matrix-of-all-possible-differences-of-a-vector-in-numpy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.subtract.outer`:

```
np.abs(np.subtract.outer(a, a))

array([[0, 2, 4, 9],
       [2, 0, 2, 7],
       [4, 2, 0, 5],
       [9, 7, 5, 0]])
```

Or equivalently use either of the followings:

```
np.abs(a - a[:, np.newaxis])
np.abs(a - a[:,  None])
np.abs(a - a.reshape((-1, 1)))
```

Comment: OP mentions that speed is critical. Perhaps post some benchmarks for the different techniques?

Comment: @ddejohn I wouldn't expect a big difference between either of these methods, since they basically do the same calculation under the hood.

Comment: Then why mention them when `np.ufunc.outer()` is much more explicit and readable? I also did memory tests and yeah, they're all equivalent. I dunno I guess I don't really see the point in offering inferior alternatives (from a readability standpoint, since that's all it comes down to).

Comment: @ddejohn I don't think they are inferior alternatives. They are more concise and also a good way to learn numpy broadcasting concept, which is ubiquitous to efficiently apply numpy techniques.